# Line Width of Table in pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pdfmake

I am working on `pdfmake.js` library for creating pdf. I need some help to change the line width of the table and cells.

My table object is

```
{
    table: {
        body: [
            [
                {
                    text: gHorse.anglesCount,
                    background: bgfcolor,
                    color: fcolor,
                    border: [ true, true, true, true ],
                    fillColor: ffcolor,
                    alignment: "center",
                    "fontSize": 6
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    margin: [ -20, 0, 0, 0 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your question is `Change` the width of the line, my answer is:

```js
content: [
  layout: {
    hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
      return (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) ? 0.1 : 0.1;
    },
    vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
      return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 0.1 : 0.1;
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a solution if you want to change borders thickness of a single cell. It actually works only for "internal" borders not for outside ones nor for a single cells borders.